# How to automate multiple files drag and drop using C# selenium?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

Am able to drag and drop a single image using the following code, am not sure what needs to be changed to support multiple files upload. Can someone help me. Thanks.

```
 driver.Url = "http://example.com";
 IWebElement droparea = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"divDrag\"]");
 DropFile(droparea, @"C:\Backup\ToBeUploaded\Image.png"); //Currently doing one file
 //DropFile(droparea, Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Backup\ToBeUploaded\")); // Expectation

 const string JS_DROP_FILE = "for(var b=arguments[0],k=arguments[1],l=arguments[2],c=b.ownerDocument,m=0;;){var e=b.getBoundingClientRect(),g=e.left+(k||e.width/2),h=e.top+(l||e.height/2),f=c.elementFromPoint(g,h);if(f&&b.contains(f))break;if(1<++m)throw b=Error('Element not interractable'),b.code=15,b;b.scrollIntoView({behavior:'instant',block:'center',inline:'center'})}var a=c.createElement('INPUT');a.setAttribute('type','file');a.setAttribute('style','position:fixed;z-index:2147483647;left:0;top:0;');a.onchange=function(){var b={effectAllowed:'all',dropEffect:'none',types:['Files'],files:this.files,setData:function(){},getData:function(){},clearData:function(){},setDragImage:function(){}};window.DataTransferItemList&&(b.items=Object.setPrototypeOf([Object.setPrototypeOf({kind:'file',type:this.files[0].type,file:this.files[0],getAsFile:function(){return this.file},getAsString:function(b){var a=new FileReader;a.onload=function(a){b(a.target.result)};a.readAsText(this.file)}},DataTransferItem.prototype)],DataTransferItemList.prototype));Object.setPrototypeOf(b,DataTransfer.prototype);['dragenter','dragover','drop'].forEach(function(a){var d=c.createEvent('DragEvent');d.initMouseEvent(a,!0,!0,c.defaultView,0,0,0,g,h,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null);Object.setPrototypeOf(d,null);d.dataTransfer=b;Object.setPrototypeOf(d,DragEvent.prototype);f.dispatchEvent(d)});a.parentElement.removeChild(a)};c.documentElement.appendChild(a);a.getBoundingClientRect();return a;";

 static void DropFile(IWebElement target, string filePath, double offsetX = 0, double offsetY = 0)
 {
      if (!File.Exists(filePath))
         throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath);
      IWebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)target).WrappedDriver;
      IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
      IWebElement input = (IWebElement)jse.ExecuteScript(JS_DROP_FILE, taget, offsetX, offsetY);
      input.SendKeys(filePath);
 }
```

Comment: Why not run this function in a loop?

Comment: It didn't work that way for some reason, I was able to do multiple files by refreshing and trying again. However in some web-pages the URL is getting lost. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

In the code below

The file address appears in the "fileLoc" section.
You can upload the image using "fileLoc".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AllowDrop = true;
        }

        private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] filePaths = (string[])(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));
                foreach (string fileLoc in filePaths)
                {
                    // Code to read the contents of the text file
                    if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
                    {
                        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileLoc))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(tr.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to drop in to my C# application. Am trying to access an URL and drop there.